# Rails: undefined method `name' for Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, koala

**Update:** part of the problem might have been solved by accessing the data like

```
first_name = graphdata[:first_name]
```

instead of like

```
first_name = userdata.first name
```

but when I go to save it, I'm now getting this error

```
 undefined method `save!' for #<Class:0x00000102dbe068>
```

**Original problem**

I'm sure there's probably multiple problems with this code.

I'm playing around with a clone of a Rails app https://github.com/banane/sample-koala-rails-app that uses Koala to authenticate with Facebook and get user data. It does this with the `callback` method in the home_controller.rb below.

I'm trying to save the authentication token and the user data to a User model that I created.

In the callback method below, I inserted this code

```
     user = User.oath(session[:access_token], @user_info)   ### my code/ likely wrong
     session[:user_id] = user.id                            ### my code/ likely wrong
```

to try to save the data to the User model, using the  'oath' class method I made on the User model (see below). Note,I'm not even sure if I can pass that instance variable @user_info into the method...

When I test it, the error I get is

```
undefined method `name' for #<Hash:0x00000103457d70>
```

and the trace says

```
app/models/user.rb:8:in `oath'
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:30:in `callback'
```

**Here's the code**

User.rb

```
def self.oath(access_token, userdata)      #my code/ likely wrong


    name = userdata.name
    first_name = userdata.first_name
    last_name = userdata.last_name
    username = userdata.username
    gender = userdata.gender
    email = userdata.email
    access_token = access_token
    save!
  end
```

Home_controller.rb  (towards the end of the callback method I try to save the user data)

```
def callback
    if params[:code]
        # acknowledge code and get access token from FB
          session[:access_token] = session[:oauth].get_access_token(params[:code])
        end     

         # auth established, now do a graph call:

        @api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(session[:access_token])
        begin
            @user_info = @api.get_object("me")
            @graph_data = @api.get_object("/me/statuses", "fields"=>"message")
        rescue Exception=>ex
            puts ex.message
        end

        user = User.oath(session[:access_token], @user_info)  #my code/likely wrong
        session[:user_id] = user.id


        respond_to do |format|
         format.html {   }           
        end


    end
```

The @user_info has all this data in it

```
{"id"=>"8331884858", "name"=>"Michael MYLASTNAME", "first_name"=>"Michael", "last_name"=>"MYLASTNAMe", "link"=>"http://www.facebook.com/myusername", "username"=>"myusername", "gender"=>"male", "email"=>"myemail", "timezone"=>5, "locale"=>"en_US", "verified"=>true, "updated_time"=>"2012-07-29T06:52:12+0000"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be just accessing the hash incorrectly, try this:

```
  def self.oath(access_token, userdata)
    create! userdata.merge({:access_token => access_token})
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, but now there's a problem with how I'm saving. It says undefined method `save!' for #<Class:0x00000102dbe068>

Comment: ok, that makes sense sort of, but I still have to pull the data from the userdata hash

Comment: That does - it combines the access token into the rest of the userdata, and creates the object from it.